# nfc.addMimeTypeListener re-opens the app again (phonegap)

Tags: javascript, android, phonegap-plugins, nfc, phonegap

So I'm trying to send information from one phone to another through NFC using phonegap. I want whatever information I send from one app to be saved as a variable at some point so I can either display it, manipulate it, etc. The issue I'm having is that whenever I try to send a text from one phone, it just opens up the app but does not display the text like it should. I have a custom Mimetype and an intent filter set up to open up the app on the other phone, so I don't believe that to be the problem.I think I may be using the addMimeTypeListener function wrong but am not too sure. Any help in clarifying my issue would be appreciated.

Here is where I call the addMimeTypeListener function in the deviceready function:

```
    deviceready: function () {
    document.getElementById('checkbox').addEventListener('change', app.toggleCheckbox, false);
    sample.addEventListener('click', app.showSampleData, false);

    nfc.addNdefListener(
        function() {
            app.notifyUser("Found an NDEF formatted tag");
        },
        function() {
            app.notifyUser("Success.");
        },
        function() {
           app.notifyUser("Fail.");
        }
    );
    nfc.addMimeTypeListener(
        "text/shunt",
        parseTag,

        function() {
           app.notifyUser("Success");
        },
        function() {
            app.notifyUser("Fail");
        }
    );
},
```

Here is where call the parsed tag function

```
    function parseTag(nfcEvent) {
var records = nfcEvent.tagData;

for (var i = 0; i < records.length; i++) {
    var record = records[i],
        p = document.createElement('p');
    p.innerHTML = nfc.bytesToString(record.payload);
    display.appendChild(p);
    app.notifyUser(p);
}
```

And here is my intent filter just for reference

```
    <application android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:icon="@mipmap/icon" android:label="@string/app_name" android:supportsRtl="true">
    <activity android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|locale" android:label="@string/activity_name" android:launchMode="singleTop" android:name="MainActivity" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.DeviceDefault.NoActionBar" android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
        <intent-filter android:label="@string/launcher_name">
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.nfc.action.NDEF_DISCOVERED" />
            <data android:mimeType="text/shunt" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

I've been trying to follow chariotsolutions examples in order to understand how it works but still not having much luck.

Thank you.

edit:
@Michael Roland

Here is the function where I send the data through NFC. This function gets called from the deviceready function. I know I am able to transmit information from one device to another with NFC. But having the app open on the other device, and display that information within the app is where I am struggling to make it work.
        shareMessage: function () {

```
    var mimeType = 'text/shunt',
        payload = 'test',
        record = ndef.mimeMediaRecord(mimeType, nfc.stringToBytes(payload));
        nfc.share([record]);
},
```

Comment: How do you send the data?

Comment: Here is the function where I send the data through NFC. This function gets called from the deviceready function. I know I am able to transmit information from one device to another with NFC. But having the app open on the other device, and display that information within the app is where I am struggling to make it work.         
        shareMessage: function () {

        var mimeType = 'text/shunt',
            payload = 'test',
            record = ndef.mimeMediaRecord(mimeType, nfc.stringToBytes(payload));
            nfc.share([record]);
    },

Answer (score 0):

This is usually fixed in the `AndroidManifest.xml`. In the past, adding `android:noHistory="true"` to the activity xml would stop Android from launching a new app. It's been a while so there might be some newer flags. See https://github.com/chariotsolutions/phonegap-nfc#launching-your-android-application-when-scanning-a-tag.